# Mailchimp - Can you show and hide content block in a custom template?

Tags: html, html-email, mailchimp

I have the joyful task of making an email template and I have a lot of content blocks that need to be coded into the template.

All of which might not always be used.

I was wondering if there is a way to hide/show content blocks for the client so they aren't stuck with the same layout?

From my own research this doesn't seem to be something that is possible.

Update
I've found that there is the `mc:hideable`
 attribute but it does not work as expected. It is fair to say it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

- if you added the  content blocks, and the template is ready - try to create a campaign, using start point your prior done template, and try to hide the blocks there, and check if that is the result what you need.